# Python: Creating own Widget with scrollbars

Tags: python, gtk, custom-controls, scrollbar, pygtk

I'm working on a X-plotter like widget that plots incomming data live.
I already searched for an solution to realize a **scrolling along the x-axis** if the widget has to much values and so they don't fit.

I had the folling approaches to realize it:

- derive from a widget that supports scrolling and child widgets and add my own widget while making it bigger and bigger during the live updates: -> Which parent do I need to use and how do I avoid to draw all the stuff that is currently not visible?
- modify my widget in a way that it supports the scrollbars itself -> but how?
- draw/handle my own scrollbars -> worstcase :(

I really searched the web for suggestions or examples, but there is nothing about how to "construct" custom controls in a good way (beyond drawing something) esp. in the case of interaction...
Sorry but I'm a newbie at GTK in general :/

Comment: Can you add some code or a link to what you're currently trying? There isn't enough context to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: @ChristianTernus
Well whole code is bit to much, but I will try to add the important stuff:
* ownwidget is based on gtk.Drawingarea)  
* placed in a VBOX on the app window  
* uses ATM only do_expose trigger to draw, no sizing requests etc.  
* internally using CAIRO to plot

Comment: Why can't you use a canvas library that gives you all of that already? Such as GooCanvas or, for more complex stuff, Clutter?

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. I wasn't aware at the start of my widget, that this part will become that tricky ;)

Comment: @gianmt So GooCanvas is for C++ and Clutter uses OpenGL. But I try to create an Python app (sry, add it to title), with minimal dependencies.

Comment: @MaM GooCanvas is written in C and since it's uses introspection have got automatic bindings for python (among the other supported languages), so for python you would do: **from gi.repository import GooCanvas**. Clutter is written in C as well and have got introspection bindings http://clutter.wikidot.com/tut:basic

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I would like to have a pure Python solution to simplify the rollout. I will try to deal with the Scrollbar things manually

Comment: @MaM I don't really get the "pure python", GTK itself it's written in C and you use python bindings, GooCanvas and Clutter are exactly the same thing, written in C and with Python bindings, I really suggest you to don't reinvent the wheel with your own implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most widgets in Gtk do **not** have scrollbars.

If you want to scroll the entire widget, you have to implement the `GtkScrollable` interface. Then, you add the widget to a `GtkScrolledWindow`. The scrolled window has the scrollbars, those `GtkScrollbars` are linked with `GtkAdjustments` which are passed to your custom widget through the `GtkScrollable` interface `set_vadjustment` and `set_hadjustment`.

If you just want to add a scrollbar and control its behaviour yourself, then you need to somehow add a `GtkScrollbar` in your widget, which means you will need to make it a container too.

The `GtkScrollable` approach is the following, first you implement `vadjustment` and `hadjustment` setters and getters, then when the `GtkAdjustments` are set, you set its lower and upper limits and the page size(how much of the widget is visible at once). After that, you connect their `value-changed` signal so you can refresh your widget when the scrollbars are dragged. A `GtkScrollable` doesn't get to check the scrollbars, only the adjustments that will be bound to the scrollbars. When drawing the widget you get the adjustments' `value` property in order to determine how much the scrollbars have shifted in the horizontal and vertical axes.

Comment: Yep, in the End I used GTKScrolledWindow and add all my stuff inside. Here it is a gtk.fixed Layout as I like to calculate my virtual position manually. So if the widgets get moved outside the current view, scrollbars appear. Briliant :)